# Manage pagination with cell in cakephp 4

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cell

With Cakephp 4 I would like to display some data. As there is too much data I would like to use pagination only I don't want to reload the whole page, just the part that displays this data. So I created a cell like this:
fileCell.php

```
public function display() {
  $results = $paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $this->request->getQueryParams(),
            [
                'limit' => 20
            ]
        );
  }
  $paging = $paginator->getPagingParams() + (array)$this->request->getParam('paging');
  $this->request = $this->request->withParam('paging', $paging);

  $this->set('res', $results);
```

and I display the pagination in my view like this:

```
<div class="instances index content">
    <div class="paginator">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?= $this->Paginator->first('<< ' . __('first')) ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->last(__('last') . ' >>') ?>
        </ul>
        <p><?= $this->Paginator->counter(__('Page {{page}} of {{pages}}, showing {{current}} record(s) out of {{count}} total')) ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Except that by doing so I reload the whole page while I would like to reload only the part concerning the cell, can someone help me?

Comment: use ajax and some js plugin to load and paginate that part of site.

Comment: thanks, I try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a standard ajax call, I create function in my controller. I create view associate corresponding to my element.
In my main view (where I will place my element), I add div :

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

And, in my ajax response I add :

```
$('#test').html(response);
```

After that, I manage the pagination of my element normally with cakephp pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I am just a beginner at Cake, but I wonder if a `finder` function in your Controller could take a page parameter?

I don't have an example, but I will soon be doing something similar.